# Custom Action Delete/Add On ComboBox in wix Installer Toolset

Tags: database, combobox, wix, windows-installer

I have a dialog (D1) that has a ComboBox where the items of the ComboBox is filled by a custom action (C++ dll).

```
UINT __stdcall FillComboBox(MSIHANDLE hInstall) 
{ 
  HRESULT hResult = WcaInitialize(hInstall, "FillComboBox");

  if (FAILED(hResult)) return ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;

  MSIHANDLE hTable = NULL;
  MSIHANDLE hColumns = NULL;


  hResult = WcaAddTempRecord(&hTable, &hColumns, L"ComboBox", NULL, 0, 3, L"COMBOBOXVALUES", 1, L"ABC");
  hResult = WcaAddTempRecord(&hTable, &hColumns, L"ComboBox", NULL, 0, 3, L"COMBOBOXVALUES", 2, L"DEF");
  hResult = WcaAddTempRecord(&hTable, &hColumns, L"ComboBox", NULL, 0, 3, L"COMBOBOXVALUES", 3, L"GHI");
}
```

When the user has selected an item the next button is enabled and another dialog (D2) is shown (if the user clicks the next button) with another combobox. The D2 combobox is also filled by a custom action in the same way as the first one but the selection of items is based on the item that was selected in the first dialog (D1).

My problem is if the user clicks the back button in dialog D2 and in the D1 dialog changes the selection of the Combobox and then clicks the next button (To move back to D2) I want to "reload" the items in the D2-ComboBox using the new value that was selected in D1.

Is there a way to clear an msi-table from the c++ code?

Can I delete the combobox table using function

```
MsiDatabaseOpenView(hDatabase, L"DELETE FROM 'ComboBox' WHERE 'Property' = 'COMBOBOXVALUES'", &hView)
```

---

Comment: Don't have time to look at this. Sorry. But how about I lob you the first link that comes to mind and see if you find something: [Stefan Kruger's Dual ListBoxes](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/articles/MultiListBox/index.htm).

Comment: And maybe [try to raid github.com for inspiration](https://github.com/search?l=C%2B%2B&q=WcaAddTempRecord&type=Code).

Comment: In the 1st link I did not found any source code, also some parts are available which is in VB Script

Comment: Yes, I thought I'd try to send you some intel since I didn't have time to really look at the question. I hope the github approach worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a property to retain and share the values across the combo boxes?

Comment: Yes, I tried... If I am modifying the table to update the combobox value by adding item to table it gives error

Comment: DEBUG: Error 2896:  Executing action FillingComboBox failed.
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2896. The arguments are: FillingComboBox, , 
Action ended 9:01:03: WelcomeDlg. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (74:F0) [09:01:03:562]: Doing action: FatalError

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way to add and delete the combobox item is to use DB concept.
You can do the direct operations on the Table writing SQL kind of query.

```
HRESULT hResult = WcaInitialize(hInstall, "FillComboBox");
if (FAILED(hResult)) return ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
MSIHANDLE hView = 0;
MSIHANDLE hDatabase = 0;
LPWSTR query;
query = L"INSERT INTO ComboBox (Property, `Order`, `Value`, `Text`) VALUES ('COMBOBOXVALUES', 1, 'Test', 'Test') TEMPORARY";
hDatabase = MsiGetActiveDatabase(hInstall);
hResult = MsiDatabaseOpenView(hDatabase, query, &hView);
if (hResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    hResult = MsiViewExecute(hView, 0);
}
```

To Delete the table you can use the below query.

```
query = L"DELETE FROM ComboBox";
```

In order to delete specific row you need to execute the below query.

```
query = L"DELETE FROM ComboBox WHERE `Order` = 1";
```